# Load cygwin C++ dll, call class functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cygwin

I need to use cygwin compiled dll from visual studio C++ or Code:blocks MinGW.

I have loaded cygwin1.dll and some other dlls, which was required, such as `cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll`, `cygstdc++-6.dll`and others. My dll is loaded normally I can get any function pointer by `GetProcAddress` function, but my problem is that

My dll is c++ dll with many classes.
I have included necessary headers But (how can I guess which function is who) 
I have different calling conventions

```
000000051a5ae590 T _ZN6eq_res8is_breakEv
000000051a5ae810 T _ZN6eq_res8is_emptyEP5EqAdr
000000051a5ae700 T _ZN6eq_res8is_localEP5EqAdr
000000051a5b00c0 T _ZN6eq_res8monitorsEv
000000051a5af4e0 T _ZN6eq_res8req_cardEi
000000051a5af560 T _ZN6eq_res8ret_cardEv
000000051a5ae540 T _ZN6eq_res8set_exitEv
000000051a5ae9d0 T _ZN6eq_res9check_refEP6eq_svr 
...
```

How can I change function calling convention for loaded dll or project in visual c++ ? 
or, How can I declare object call constructor, destructor for an object and use other class functions from dll ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing Visual Stusio and Cygwin means to look for troubles.
Some hints are given here

https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.msvs-mingw

But remember that the two worlds uses different conventions and for 64bit also different type size.

https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.64bitporting

Comment: Thanks my cygwin dll is 64 bit, maybe it is troubles, but unfortunately I have started and have to finish, I think I can overcome types by macroses, and one more thing ,  I could not make work `printf` or `cout` functions that are working with terminals.